# Result list in JSON format spring boot

Tags: json, spring

Hello im trying to return a list of numbers in Json form with a small spring Rest API application
here is my controller :

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.controller;

import java.util.Scanner;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

@RestController
public class Number {

@GetMapping(value = "/")
public int getNumber() { 
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    Scanner saisie = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = saisie.nextInt();
    for(int i = 1 ; i<=number; i++) {
        
    if( i % 3 == 0) {
        
        System.out.println("Fizz");
        
    } else if (i % 5 == 0 ) {
        
        System.out.println("Buzz");
        
    } else if (i % 3 == 0 && i %5 == 0) {
        
        System.out.println("FizzBuzz");
        
    } else {
        
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    }

    return number;
}
}
```

i want to display the list of results list in a JSON format, any help please ?

Comment: do you want to print the JSON in the console or on the browser?

Answer (score 0):

```
I just updated your code and make some changes, you're trying to implement a REST API so you should get your data from path params or request body, use logger instead of the system. out and when you will return a response body you will get it in JSON format




 package net.javaguides.springboot.controller;
    
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    import com.softilys.soyouz.dto.helpers.JiraKeyDTO;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    
    import com.google.gson.Gson;
    
    @RestController
    public class NumberController {
    
        private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    
        @GetMapping(value = "/{number}")
        public ResponseEntity<Integer> getNumber(@PathVariable String number) {
    
            for(int i = 1 ; i<= Integer.parseInt(number); i++) {
    
                if( i % 3 == 0) {
    
                    log.info("Fizz");
    
                } else if (i % 5 == 0 ) {
    
                    log.info("Buzz");
    
                } else if (i % 3 == 0 && i %5 == 0) {
    
                    log.info("FizzBuzz");
    
                } else {
    
                    log.info(""+i);
                }
            }
    
            return new ResponseEntity<Integer>(Integer.valueOf(number), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
```